# How can I get more people to join the Mindstorms subreddit?

Tags: promotion, reddit

I've been the mod for quite a while and I've been trying to pick up the traffic the subreddit gets but I have had little to no results.

I tried challenge threads and no one bothers. I've done discussion threads and people actually take their time to reply but not many.

I really want it to be a content filled sub but if no one is posting content then no one shows up and if no one shows up then no content gets posted. What could I do to get the word out there to get people to flock over?

As for the current state of the sub the most attention it gets is questions and I do my best to answer as many as I can to the best of my ability. It's alive but barely.

Comment: Can you change or narrow the focus of the subreddit to make it more interesting? It seems that mindstorms in general is covered by several sites and forums.

Comment: what narrow focus did you have in mind?

Comment: I don't know mindstorms enough to make a suggestion. When I type "mindstorms" in reddit, there are immediately a whole range of entries about robotics etc, videos, images, texts. So I guess there is interest, but not in another general topic forum, but some niche that is not covered yet. You could make a poll or open a meta discussion among the 1500 users (can I assume that you are not in one of the 8-users groups :)? ).